# Downsides of using 5mm fuses in 6.3mm sockets

Tags: safety, multimeter, fuses

For my multimeter I need to replace a fuse. It is 6.3mm in diameter, 25mm long, rated 500mA/250V AC and 1500A interrupt rating.

I have a couple of such fuses, but they are 5mm in diameter, and looking online here in Germany I can't seem to find 6.3x25mm ones. So I was wondering in general (but of course mostly specific to my multimeter):

Are there any downsides in bending the fuse holders just a bit (1.3mm)? Assume that the fuse can not easily fall of, at most lose contact. I am mostly interested in safety issues here, I can live with the fuse needed to be reset from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main things for safety are the **interrupting capacity** and the **voltage rating**. If you are **sure** that the replacement meets or exceeds the original specification, you should be okay.

Presumably this is to replace an ABC style fuse.

This type of fuse is **not** considered safe under [IEC 61010-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) for use on equipment directly connected to the mains (Cat II and above).

Comment: Good to know, but I think the multimeter manual explicitly states that the 200mA plug is not to be used for mains, and the Cat2/3 plug has interupting rating of 100kA which should be enough for single phase main I think.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have seen serious problems with replacing 3AG (glass) fuses with European style 5 x 20mm glass fuses (arcing end-to-end and explosions), but that was on 240VAC with maybe 1000A fault current.

Comment: Aren't the 5mm fuses also *shorter* (20mm vs. 25mm)? Maybe you could use the end caps from the blown fuse to make "adapter caps" for the new fuse so that you don't have to mangle the fuse holder.

Comment: @DaveTweed: yes, you are right, I guess I shouldn't think about such things too late in the night... it is indeed 5mm shorter!

Comment: @PlasmaHH 5.4mm shorter. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I intend to use 1500A or better interrupt rated sand filled ceramic ones. Now that I know they are even shorter, you think I should edit the question accordingly?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't think it affects the question about safety, so I say it's not necessary. Of course I knew you meant the 6.35mm \$\phi\$ x25.4mm (1/4"\$\phi\$ x 1") size of fuse (ABC).